# Azure Pipelines: How to have a permission limited resource let forks pass without access?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to have this job only check out the second repository when it has permission (which I can check in a simple condition). I currently only have permission for my repo (eg name: tobylane.tobylane.github.io), as would any other user who forks. End result is that this can be merged into the main repository and when someone forks it, it doesn't break but instead skips this resources step.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: docs
      type: github
      endpoint: github
      name: org.org.github.io
- job: Docs
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: docs
        persistCredentials: true  # Keeps the git OAuth token after checkout
        condition: eq( 'Org/Org', variables['Build.Repository.Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test , when the `check out` step doesn't meet the condition, the step will skip instead of failing.

If you want to directly fail the job, you could add a `Powershell Task` and use the [Logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash)

**Update:**

You could try to use [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) to to distinguish situations.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- checkout: self

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'Org/Org') }}:
    - checkout: docs
- ${{ if ne(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'Org/Org') }}:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]DONE"'
```

In this case , if the task could meet the condition, it will run the `check out` step.
Otherwise, it will not run this step.

Result:
Meet the condition:

[image: Result1]

Not Meet the condition:

[image: Result2]

Comment: I can stop the checkout from happening, as I have in the code I posted, but I need to stop the resource from being accessed.

Comment: @tobylane   I have updated my answer. Please check if it could meet your requirements. When I use expressions, it can automatically determine whether to run the `checkout` step.

Comment: I think I can't control the resources stage with expressions or conditions, so it's a missing feature or limitation. I'll come back to this when I can, I believe your solution applied to the resources stage is what it should be.

Comment: If you have any update, please feel free to contact us. I will be here to help you. Also if you can be sure that this answer could work , you may consider accepting it.

Comment: I asked here because it seems like the right place https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1072878/allow-expressions-andor-conditions-in-the-resource.html

Comment: Yes . This is our User Voice Site. You could report the feature request in the Site.

Comment: Is the user voice site Stackoverflow or my link? I used the suggest a feature button on the developer community. I hope I'm in the right place, rather than having to use a third site.

Comment: It's your link. If you want to report a suggestion, the link is the correct place.